# Sockets or Ajax. What should I use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

### What I want

I want to create a login script using Nodejs. At the moment I am considering using sockets or ajax posts.

### What I have

I have installed Nodejs, and used [this code](https://github.com/clocklimited/BasicExpressSite).

### What I tried

I began with a simple Ajax post. I used jQuery for this and I serialized the form. This worked but sometimes it has some delay or it was slow.

So I thought maybe sockets is a better way to communicate with the server and back to the client.

Now I'm facing the problem that I can't use `serialize()` anymore (damn I loved that `serialize()` function).

So now I have to use json in my client, getting the 2 input values (email and password), make an object called `obj`, add the values and use `socket.emit('login', JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2))`

In my server I have

```
socket.on('login', function(data){
   data = JSON.parse(data)
   if(data.email === 'em@il.com' && data.password === 'secret')
        // return true
   // return false
})
```

Now the problem is that I am unable to let my client know if the credentials are correct.

I could do this by using another `emit` but I think this would be overload.

Can't I just use `return true` or maybe `socket.send(true)`?

Anyone have the same problem? Or maybe the solution to my problem?

Thanks!!

Comment: `I could do this by using another emit but I think this would be overload.`. Why? this the way to inform the client with socket.io. If you want the request/response model of communication, you should use ajax post.

Comment: +1 just make sure you sending the emit to the specific user only

Comment: you might want a normal form with a submit button as a non-JS fallback. also after debugging you can remove the (,null,2) from your stringify call to shorten the strings you pass

Comment: No non-JS fallback needed, my application needs javascript, Thanks for the tip about stringify ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, dude, it smells like it wont be the only function that you will call from your client. So you should start designing your API.

If you send JSON from client, then the most honorable thing to do from the server is to return JSON. I would use socket.send.

A basic OK response would look like this:

```
{ "Status" : true }
```

A basic Error response would look like this:

```
{ "Status" : false, "Message": "Login or password not valid" }
```

If in the future you need to return data to your client, then the same basic entity might be used you just need to add more attributes to it and read it in the client.

```
{ "Status" : true, Data: { /* data here */ } }
```

Comment: That would be a great solution. But how can I catch these responses after an `emit()`? Or you mean that I should use socket emit from server to client?

Comment: Well, you should have on the client something like socket.on('logonComplete', function(data){ ... })   in the server you emit a 'logonComplete' object with the data you need in the client.

Comment: Ah so it is sockets :) Thanks